# Await for an async queue to be proceeded (async module)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, queue, async.js

I'm trying to build a queue with nodejs and async module but it's not working as desired.

Here is my code:

```
const async = require('async');

const queueSize = 10;
const taskHandler = function (task, done) {
    task(done);
};

const myQueue = async.queue(taskHandler, queueSize);

myQueue.drain = function () {
    console.log('The queue is now empty.');
};

function delay() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}

async function delayedLog(item) {
    await delay();
    console.log(item);
}

const run = async () => {
    for (let item = 0; item < 30; item++) {
        myQueue.push(async function (done) {
            await delayedLog(item)
            done();
        });
    }
}

(async () => {
    console.log('START');
    await run();
    console.log('END);
})()
```

What I want:

```
START
// logs from delayedLog
END
```

Output:

```
START
END 
// logs from delayedLog
```

As you can see await isn't working. I tried to promisify the module but the problem is still here. I tried with d3-queue and I had exactly the same problem.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Chiến Nghê said you are using some async/await where there is no need to but this is another problem.

Your await isn't working at the end because your drain function is called at the end of your queue and it's not returning a promise.

You have to promisify your function, here is a sample example to do that:

```
function end() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        myQueue.drain = function () {
            console.log('The queue is now empty.');
            resolve();
        };
    })
}
```

And then you can use your async await on your end function:

```
(async () => {
    console.log('START');
    run();
    await end();
    console.log('END');
})()
```

Output:

```
START
// a lot of logs
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is working as it is. Actually you dont need to declare `async` for function `run()`. This function is simply to put 30 async tasks to the queue for later execution then it ends after that.

I don't know exact what you want, but if you want the `console.log('END')` logic is executed only every async tasks in queue are finished. Please move it to queue's `drain()` function.

Comment: the purpose is to await the end of the queue to process other stuffs , the real code launch multiples post to a server, I got to wait all the responses to insert datas in a database 
aftfer that got to do it again with other data 

(async () => {
    console.log('START');
    await run( process1);

    await run( process1);

    console.log('END);
})()

Comment: sorry I hit enter too many times 

The final purpose is a main like this

(async () => {
    console.log('START');

    await run( process1);
    await saveToDB(responses1);
    await run( process2);
    await saveToDB(responses2);
    await run( process3);
    await saveToDB(responses3);

    console.log('END);
})()

Comment: My opinion is you put your "other stuffs" to queue drain() function. Because once you registered tasks to async queue, nowhere other than drain() could be the point for end queue event detection. It's reason why this drain() function exists.

Comment: exactly ! 
the drain is only way, so I did what @Curse said I promisified it  and await it in the main process
So I can chain multiple task in a clean way
 ( it's part of much bigger project of course so i cannot keep the code directly in the drain function ) ,
 thank's both

Comment: btw regarding no nedded async / await